# Flutter Riverpod : how to use consumer widget in slivers

Tags: flutter, riverpod

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(),
          Consumer(
            builder: (context, watch, child) {
              return watch(recordProvider).when(
                data: (records) {
                  // how to returns a set of Widgets(SliverPersistentHeader and SliverList) based on each item of records, 
                }, 
                loading: () => const SliverToBoxAdapter(),
                error: (obj, error) => const SliverToBoxAdapter(),
              );
            },
          ),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am new to flutter, want to know how to returns a set of Widgets(SliverPersistentHeader and SliverList) based on each item of records in List? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Howdy and welcome to Flutter. Slivers are a lot more complicated than using the other higher level widgets so bare with me on this answer. The code is documented with what's going on and it's using a very primitive list of data to build the `CustomScrollView`, just a `List<int>`.

```dart
/// fake FutureProvider
final recordProvider = FutureProvider(
  (ref) => Future.value(
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  ),
);

/// Our page of records
class RecordPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const RecordPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Consumer(
        builder: (context, watch, child) {
          /// Building a list of our slivers up front so that it's easier to read
          final List<Widget> slivers = watch(recordProvider).when(
            data: (records) {
              /// Lets split up some data so we can have our persistent headers hold some lists
              final even = records.where((element) => element & 1 == 0);
              final odd = records.where((element) => element & 1 == 1);

              /// Now we need to take that data and make some lists of widgets
              final evenWidgets =
                  even.map((e) => RecordWidget(record: e)).toList();
              final oddWidgets =
                  odd.map((e) => RecordWidget(record: e)).toList();

              /// Now let's make some SliverLists
              final evenSliverList = SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate.fixed(evenWidgets),
              );
              final oddSliverList = SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate.fixed(oddWidgets),
              );

              /// Now let's create some headers
              const evenHeader = SliverPersistentHeader(
                delegate: RecordPersistentHeader('Even'),
              );

              const oddHeader = SliverPersistentHeader(
                delegate: RecordPersistentHeader('Odd'),
              );

              /// Now let's merge them all together and return the slivers
              return [
                evenHeader,
                evenSliverList,
                oddHeader,
                oddSliverList,
              ];
            },
            loading: () => [const SliverToBoxAdapter()],
            error: (obj, error) => [const SliverToBoxAdapter()],
          );

          /// Finally let's return our [CustomScrollView] with our list of slivers
          return CustomScrollView(
            slivers: slivers,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// The contents of our record sliver
class RecordWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const RecordWidget({Key? key, required this.record}) : super(key: key);

  final int record;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('$record');
  }
}

/// The contents of our header sliver
class RecordPersistentHeader extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  const RecordPersistentHeader(this.title);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Text(title);
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 40;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 40;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image: CustomScrollView screenshot]

Comment: error on this line:  element & 1 == 0  how to fix it, thanks !

Comment: uh, what's the error?

Comment: your data source won't be a list of ints... that was just a fake data source for demonstration purposes... you need to fill in that data method with your needs.

Comment: You're data source will most likely be something like a list of Models. You'll want a widget that takes that model and makes a visual representation. Same goes for the head with the header delegate.

Comment: records is type of List<Transaction>, show me : The operator '&' isn't defined for the type 'Transaction'.
Try defining the operator '&'.

Comment: `element & 1 == 0` in this scenario `element` is an `int`. the expression just figures out if it's even or not. You _do not_ need this.

Comment: .......... I was wrong about something, sorry

Comment: thanks a lot man !  other thing, can use consumer widget in List<widget> dynamic ? forexample: [widget, consumer, widget]

Comment: I don't know what `consumer` is... Like a riverpod consumer? Not sure why you would do that but `Consumer` is a widget so it would also conform to `List<Widget>`.

Comment: sorry, My English is not good enough.  it doesn't matter, the problem has been solved, you help me a lot ! thanks ! have a good day !